# Kendo Grid filter event with OData

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have a kendo grid with a `dataSource` and the dataSource has the following options:

```
type: "odata-v4",
serverFiltering: true,
serverPaging: true,
serverSorting: true
```

Within the grid options I have the following:

```
sortable: true,
resizable: true,
reorderable: true,
filterable: true,
filter: function(e) {
   console.log(e)
},
```

However the `filter` event never fires.  Is it possible to perform server side filtering and have the `filter` event fire?  I need to get hold of the filter before the `dataSource` performs any operations and extend the filter and therefore would prefer to do this without writing custom code for the dataSource.

**Edit**
I have a custom filter on the column I'm trying to trap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grid's [`filter`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filter) event was introduced in Kendo UI version **2016.3.914** - if you are using an older version, please upgrade.

Comment: It would be great if this was in the Telerik documentation.  Thanks for the help.